# Using event listening wait for readyState html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Here is my javascript on loading of video.

```
var vid = $("#video");

$("#video").on("load",function() {
    if ( vid[0].ReadyState === 4 ) {
        console.log("loaded video!");
        console.log(vid);
        vid.fadeIn();
    }
});
```

I want to play my video everytime the video div refreshes after `.load()` runs. How do i loop this until `readyState == 4`? I tried using `on("canplaythrough")` but this is never recognized as a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set `preload="auto"` (and don't use `autoplay`) in the tag, then you can use the `canplay` event:

```js
var vid = $("#video");

vid.on("canplay", function() {
  vid[0].play();
  vid.fadeIn(1000);
});

$("#change").on("click", function() {
  vid.hide();
  vid[0].src = "http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" width="500" height="280" preload="auto" style="display:none">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<button id="change">Change source (mp4 only for this example)</button>
```

Comment: Will this work if I am changing the src attribute on the page?

Comment: @pwneth I think so, it should trigger a new canplay event.

Comment: also, when I look at the object in console, the canplay event is always null... so i'm guessing it will never fire.

Comment: @pwneth it's important to define preload. As seen in the demo above, canplay is triggered as expected.

Comment: no problem (added a src change button in the demo as well)

Comment: is there any reason why in safari the looping of video cuts between restarting?

Comment: @pwneth I can't say I know 100% what they are doing in Safari but there have been and are several issues with video/buffering/canvas in Safari. There's not so much we can do about it though :-/ You could open a new question and see if anyone has some input on this problem.

Comment: yeah, seems like its a common problem, with no solution :/

Comment: It's 2023 and this no longer works.